# How can a non-working corroded tub plunger with a broken linkage assembly in the open position be fixed?

Tags: drain, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures, corrosion

I’ve read the helpful advice on  bathtub plungers  stuck  in the closed position. However, I have a bathtub plunger stuck in the open position. The trip assembly has come away leaving the plunger in place with The tub not holding water. The CLR used to help uncorrode the plunger, immediately  drains away.  How do I get the plunger free from it’s corrosion so I can use as a hopeful retrieval aid( suggested) a hooked coat-hanger to snag the plunger?

Comment: A picture would be a big help so we can identify the type drain stopper you have. You mention a broken linkage assembly. Do you know for certain it's broken? If so, that linkage will need to be replaired before dealing with corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a coat hanger really helps and on some hard to snag models a bore scope may be helpful.

I have used a long screwdriver to push on a stuck stopper sometimes it’s not corrosion but hair and soap buildup under the stopper that is the problem,

removing the drain will occasionally pull a rat of hair up that is preventing the stopper from dropping into place and blocking the flow.

Make sure to check for obstructions below as the stopper is gravity closure so a chunk of hair could be the problem also.